# Como pesquisar em uma dropdownlist?

Tags: c#

Tenho uma Dropdown que lista o nome de todos os bancos. Preciso criar um método no qual ele me traz um set de resultados e dentre eles o nome do banco. Esse banco que a minha lista trouxer(apenas um registro) deverá fazer com que minha Dropdownlist mostre esse nome, como se fosse uma pesquisa dentro da drop, não sei se fui claro.

Ok, vou explicar. Tenho uma combo ou dropdown que me lista todas as instituições bancárias. Tenho uma pesquisa que retorna o nome do banco, pelo CPF ou CNPJ do pesquisado. O que eu quero é que quando eu  retornar, por exemplo, Banco Bradesco a combo deverá mostrar Banco Bradesco. Não consigo fazer isso em uma combo. Já tentei fazer com for e não consigo trazer nada.

João tem uma conta no Itaú e ele está cadastrado no meu sistema. Quando eu digitar o CPF ou CNPJ do João, vai me trazer o Nome do Banco, Agência e Conta. Só que existe uma combo com o nome das instituições num panel que será exibido. Gostaria que o retorno mostrasse no combo o nome do banco. Os txt eu já preenchi com Conta e Agência e Número do banco, mas estou tendo dificuldade de mostrar o nome do banco porque está em uma combo. Se o nome do banco não existir no Combo, então dou uma mensagem e faço o que tenho que fazer. É `WEBFORM`

A minha dificuldade está exatamente é no momento de mostrar o texto. Fiz assim e não consigo mostrar o texto. Onde nm_banco é o número do banco ou o value da combo.

```
for (int i = 0; i < cmbBancos.Items.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        if (cmbBancos.Items[i].Value == nm_banco)
                            cmbBancos.Text = cmbBancos.Items[i].Text;
                    }
```

Comment: Não foi claro, afinal nem colocou o código onde monta o controle e o que já tentou fazer.

Comment: Exemplo. Tenho em uma combo 100 nomes de banco. Aí em minha pesquisa no BD eu trago Itaú BBA SA. O que eu quero é que quando eu trouxer, a minha combo me mostre exatamente esse texto: Banco Itaú BBA SA.

Comment: Quando você se refere a banco, parece que você está se referindo as "databases", isto deixou a sua questão confusa. Reformule ela por favor.

Comment: Não é só isto, falta total contexto de como a lista está montada, faz diferença. Eu não sei nem se usti é Windows Forms, ASP.Net ou outra coisa. Acho que alguém com quase 2K de reputação já deveria ter aprendido que sem informações relevantes, não dá para responder alguma coisa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cmbBancos.SelectedValue = nm_banco;
cmbBancos_SelectedIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```